# Mostrar div segun lo seleccionado en un Select

Tags: html5, angularjs, sass

estoy intentando mostrar y ocultar un div según lo seleccionado en un select.

El Select se carga dinamicamente con un JSON

JSON

```
"BISI": [{
    "numOrden": "01",
    "codigo": "1",
    "valor": "List Item1",
    "servicio": "servicio",
    "recurso": ""
},{
    "numOrden": "02",
    "codigo": "2",
    "valor": "List Item2",
    "servicio": "servicio1",
    "recurso": "recurso1"
},{
    "numOrden": "03",
    "codigo": "3",
    "valor": "List Item3",
    "servicio": "servicio2",
    "recurso": ""
},{
    "numOrden": "04",
    "codigo": "4",
    "valor": "List Item4",
    "servicio": "servicio3",
    "recurso": "recurso3"
},{
    "numOrden": "05",
    "codigo": "5",
    "valor": "List Item5",
    "servicio": "",
    "recurso": ""
},{
    "numOrden": "06",
    "codigo": "6",
    "valor": "List Item6",
    "servicio": "",
    "recurso": "recurso6"
},{
    "numOrden": "07",
    "codigo": "7",
    "valor": "List Item7",
    "servicio": "servicio7",
    "recurso": "recurso7"
},{
    "numOrden": "08",
    "codigo": "8",
    "valor": "List Item8",
    "servicio": "",
    "recurso": "recurso8"
}],
```

el select carga en el option el codigo y el valor y lo que intento hacer es que según lo seleccionado, tiene servicio y recurso, es decir, por ej selecciono la **opción 7**, esta dispone de servicio y recurso y se mostraría el div, pero seleccionando otra opción en el que el servicio , el recurso o las 2 opciones estén vacías, el div quedaría oculto

HTML del Select

```
<select class="select-generico"
   data-ng-class="createProvRequestForm.selectBISI_F.$error.required && validar.mostrarErrores?'-error':''"
   data-ng-options="bisi.codigo as bisi.valor for bisi in createProvRequestData.BISI"
   id="selectBISI" name="selectBISI_F" data-ng-model="createProvRequestView.selectBISI"
   data-ng-disabled="!createProvRequestData.identificador || createProvRequestFunctionality.error000297" data-ng-required="true">
   <option value="" data-translate>createProvRequest-seleccionar-bisi</option>
</select>
```

HTML del div a mostrar

```
<div class="row" data-ng-hide="createProvRequestView.selectBISI.servicio !== '' && createProvRequestView.selectBISI.recurso !== ''">
     <div class="col6">
          <label class="label-general" data-translate>createProvRequest-espec-origen</label>
          <select class="select-generico"
                  data-ng-class="createProvRequestForm.selectBISI_F.$error.required && validar.mostrarErrores?'-error':''"
                  data-ng-options="recurso.codigo as recurso.valor for recurso in createProvRequestData.recurso"
                  id="selectRecurso" name="selectRecurso_F" data-ng-model="createProvRequestView.selectRecurso">
                  <option value="" data-translate>createProvRequest-seleccionar-recurso</option>
          </select>
   </div> 
   <div class="col6">
        <label class="label-general" data-translate>createProvRequest-espec-destino</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="input_generico fieldname bottom_campo" id="ident-recurso" name="especificador destino" placeholder="{{ 'createProvRequest-ident-recurso' | translate }}">
   </div>
```

pero al meter el data-ng-hide en el DIV no me funciona

> data-ng-hide="createProvRequestView.selectBISI.servicio !== '' && createProvRequestView.selectBISI.recurso !== ''"

Angular que carga el Select

```
$scope.loadMultilanguage = function () {
            T3_CabeceraPresentacionService.resolveTranslationsCG($scope.name, gettextCatalog.currentLanguage);
            /*Carga de enumerados */
            T3_LanguageService.getTecnicalEnum('createProvRequest', gettextCatalog.currentLanguage).then(function (data) {
                $scope.createProvRequestData.BISI = data.BISI;

            });
        };
```

aquí carga todos los datos del JSON

> $scope.createProvRequestData.BISI = data.BISI;

para mostrar o no el div, no me funciona y seleccionando cualquier opción, no se me muestra nada. También lo intenté con data-ng-if pero tampoco me funcionó

Alguien me podría ayudar por favor